# Put a vertical slider to the left or right of an html object

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, range

I have a canvas that displays video, and I want to bind a range slider to the left or right side of it. CSS is proving to really fight with me on this one. I can deal with stretching or slider values but just binding it to the side of that canvas is what is proving very difficult. Any help is greatly appreciated. If it's any easier to explain with a horizontal slider I will also be binding one to the bottom, may be simpler since I'm not rotating the style of the slider.

HTML:

```
<div class="centerVideo">
  <canvas id="video-canvas" style="width: 1024px; height: 576px"></canvas>


    <div style="float: right; position: fixed;">
        <form name="verticalForm">
            <output name="verticalValue" for="verticalRange" id="verticalLabel" style="font-size:22px;">Tilt: </output>

            <span style="font-size:12px;">0</span>


            <input type="range" style="transform:rotate(270deg);" name="verticalInput" id="verticalID" value="0" min="-90" max="0" oninput="tilt(this.value)">
             <script>
                    function tilt(val) {
                       //do stuff
                    }
                    </script>
                    <br>
                    <span style="font-size:12px;">-90</span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centerVideo {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Codepen https://codepen.io/thisisloop/pen/gOaBLjE
I added your Slider to the left of the screen and added a class to the slider div.
Inside this class I added:

```
position: relative;
right: 15%; //for changing the horizontal position can also use "left:"
bottom: 510px; //for changing the vertical position can also use "top:"
```

You could do this more cleaner if you used flexbox or grid, here are some nice ressources to learn: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
These are essential for making good layouts.

Hope I could help you